# Add attachment in MongoDB document field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I am looking for a solution to add attachment in a MongoDB document. For example, suppose I have a document like this in MongoDB,

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e3bff8d1c9d4400009b85be",
        "title": "Post 1 Title",
        "author": "Author 1"
    }
]
```

I want to attach a file in this same document. I have a field in the front end form to select the file to attach. 
I went thru GridFS documentation and I got to know that it can be used to store attachments in MongoDB. But I am little lost in figuring out how to attach/delete that file in the document. I am new to MongoDB so Hope I am making some sense here..

Any help on this is very much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: GridFS is a way to store things larger than 16MB by splitting them into smaller chunks.  If you want to attach something directly to this document, serialize it and add it to the document before you store it.

Comment: Can you please share link of any example or documentation on serialize...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not store "documents and files in mongodb" because it will make your database heavy and can slow the query speed.
If you want to store files or document then you can use aws s3 or your local machine and the name of file or document you can store into mongodb.
Your document will look some what like this.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e3bff8d1c9d4400009b85be",
        "title": "Post 1 Title",
        "author": "Author 1",
        "file": "image.png"
    }
]
```

Now using any language fetch the name of the file and open it.

> **Note** In real world mostly files are stored in this way.

**Thank You**